# Is sending a CV with recommendation letter a good idea?

Tags: recommendation-letter

My coworker requested me to write a recommendation letter for an academic position  (postdoc). I myself am a postdoc, and afraid that my name may not be known well enough.

In order **to support my credentials**, I was thinking of either including a short bio or attaching a full CV with my recommendation letter. Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a little unusual. Typically you insert relevant material into the letter. Something like

> Dear So and So,
>       I'm awesome in these 10 different ways
>
> Now let me tell you about Candidate.